# Can't Login Admin Panel, Return's Blank Page

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

I've moved my project from local to live but I can't login to my admin panel, it's returning a blank page I've tried giving permission to **var/session** **var/cache**(and cleared them) media folders etc. but still the problem persist.

But the frontend is working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your store to developer mode then open admin page to see the error. Also check system.log if there is any error. After you have seen the error on admin you can write in comment. Basically we will have more info about it thanks

Comment: I can't access the admin panel then how can I switch to developer mode?? Already checked system.log nothing is updating there.

Comment: To switch to developer mode go to index.php then remove comment from ini_set('display_errors',1) . After that write this code on index.php Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true). Then run the admin blank page

Comment: Thanks @Ledian, After turning on developer mode I got this error   `Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT'  in /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed.php on line 159`

Comment: Thanks @Ledian it's because of curl installation issue, i just reinstalled curl and now it's working..

Comment: I am glad that I helped. Thanks for accepting my answe. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a white page on admin login after I undeployed some modman modules and deployed them at a normal way via git. The frontend worked though.

I lost all hope and tried everything, nothing worked. At the end I had to execute `git clean -f -d` and then clear the cache, then it worked again.

**But be very cautious with this, you can loose data and changes!!!**

First execute `git status` to list all changes and look if there are important changes which you need to keep, e.g. someone from my team made a change to the cron.sh file.